# MySQL to XML

Tags: php, mysql

I want to convert my entire MySQL Table into XML... Can anyone Help me out with a tutorial or code.

Comment: Do you want to do this once, or routinely through a web interface?

Comment: use phpMyAdmin to export in various formats including XML

Answer (score 3):

mysqldump is able to dump data in XML format ; so, with something like this, you might get what you want :

```
mysqldump --user=USER --password=PASSWORD --host=HOST --xml DATABASE TABLE
```

For more information, see [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_xml)

Comment: What if i need it automatically each and every time

Comment: each and every time... that what occurs ?
An insertion / update / deletion ?
Well... If your table is big, you should probably not use this too often ^^

Can't you get the dump generated, say, once every day (or hour), via a cron job ?

If the table is small and you need this xml dump always up to date... maybe a solution not based on mysqldump (ie, based on code) would be better...

Answer (score 3):

For a simple highscore list for an iPhone [game](http://memention.com/lunarlander) I wrote a small php thingy...its output can be viewed [here](http://memention.com/eagle_highscores.php)

```
<highscores>
<?php   
// connection information
  $hostName = "xxxx";
  $userName = "xxxx";
  $password = "xxxx";
  $dbName = "xxxx";

  mysql_connect($hostName, $userName, $password) 
                 or die("Unable to connect to host $hostName");

  mysql_select_db($dbName) or die( "Unable to select database $dbName");

  $query = "SELECT * FROM HIGHSCORES ORDER BY Distance, Fuel DESC LIMIT 10";

  $result = mysql_query($query);

  $number = mysql_numrows($result);

  for ($i=0; $i<$number; $i++) {

    print "  <entry>\n";
    printf("    <Num>%d</Num>\n", $i+1);;

    $Nic = mysql_result($result, $i, "Nic");
    print "    <Nic>$Nic</Nic>\n";

    $Distance = mysql_result($result, $i, "Distance");
    printf( "    <Distance>%.9f</Distance>\n", $Distance);

    $Fuel = mysql_result($result, $i, "Fuel");
    printf( "    <Fuel>%.9f</Fuel>\n", $Fuel);

    print "  </entry>\n";

  }

  mysql_close();

?>
</highscores>
```

Comment: But i am not able to construe the $nic or distance... how will actually call my field names with attributes.

Comment: You want it to create XML entries automatically without knowing the table structure? This adds another layer of complexity...I know my table and output only what I need, the table is actually bigger and holds more information.

Comment: I need a to create XML entries for my field names with values.

Comment: "Nic" and "Distance" are fields in the table. $Nic and $Distance are variables that holds an entries values for these fields. They are then printed (outputted) in a XML format...

Answer (score 1):

mysql outputs an XML document if you use -X or --xml option:

mysql -X -e "SELECT * FROM mytable" dbname

Answer (score 0):

The mysql documentation has a page on [using XML with MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html).  It would be easy to use that method with a [`system`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) call to get the data already as XML and save yourself some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the feature, but [XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/products/xmlspy/xmlspy.html) can create a schema from the database structure. It will also convert data or map it to XML based on an existing DTD or schema.